# Find as many non-isomorphic self-complementary graphs as possible (with up to $7$ vertices)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Find as many non-isomorphic self-complementary graphs as possible with
>   up to $7$ vertices. State why there aren't more.

I've checked what a self-complementary graph is and wikipedia is saying: "A self-complementary graph is a graph which is isomorphic to its complement."

So then what is a non-isomorphic self-complementary graph? A graph which is non-isomorphic to its complement?

Here are some I found but I'm not sure if this is correct. All in all, this sounds very confusing, contradicting. Or did I just understand it wrong? How would  you find more graphs?

[image]

**Editing my question for Henning Makholm's answer:**

[image]

Comment: A graph can't be "non-isomorphic" by itself, just like a positive integer can't be "coprime" by itself. Perhaps it would be clearer if the question said "find as many self-complementary graphs as possible with up to 7 vertices, up to isomorphism".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples are only one example, since they are isomorphic.

It will help your search to notice that $K_6$ and $K_7$ both have an *odd* number of edges, so there is no self-complementary graph on $6$ or $7$ vertices. Having $2$ or $3$ vertices is taken care of by the same argument, and you have already found the single example (up to isomorphism) on $4$ vertices.

What is left for you is then only to enumerate graphs with $5$ vertices and $5$ edges, and check which of them are self-complementary.

Comment: I have just edited my question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @cnmesr: Yes, that is one. There is at least one more with $5$ vertices, in addition to the trivial graph.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what exactly is the reason there aren't more of these kind of graphs (with more than $7$ vertices)?

Comment: @cnmesr: Who says there aren't more? There are at least two with 8 vertices.